# Android data compression mechanism?

Tags: android, compression

I am working on an Android app that compresses videos, images and text, then sends them to a server, or the other way round. My server runs on Linux so I am pretty sorted out in terms of data compression, choice of libraries and language. However, my problem lies on Android.

I've been unable to find any library that effectively handles data compression. Building one is an option of course but I have not the time. I've seen apps like Whatsapp do some data compression on Android and thought anyone might have an idea of how they do this.

Could anyone help me out please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on context of your task, you can try using `java.util.zip.Inflater` and `java.util.zip.Deflater`, e.g. something like [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-compress-and-uncompress)

Comment: "I'm working on an Android app that compresses videos, images and text" - most image and video formats are already compressed.

Comment: @CommonsWare They're compressed alright, but I want to compress them further.

Comment: @alexk I think your comment would've made a good answer.

Comment: "I want to compress them further" -- you might wish to explain, **in detail**, how you plan to do that. Ignore Android for the moment. For example, you seem to think that ZIP (`java.util.zip`) will be useful, based on your last comment. If you try it using the command line **`zip`** utility on Linux, you will notice that it has little effect on common image (e.g., PNG, JPEG) and video (e.g., MP4) files. Users will be displeased with the amount of *their* CPU and battery that you consume chasing a couple of meager percent savings in size.

Comment: Thanks, but IMO @CommonsWare idea is nicer - you may consider using other format, which is less space-consuming by its nature. Compress PNG more with PNG compression properties or use some kind of alternative video codec for MP4 - this may help and will not require one more layer for dealing with your data, both on client and server sides.

Comment: Probably you should look into Whatsapp. **Images, videos and audios are compressed on the sender's device**. These compressed versions are *always* of smaller sizes. How does one explain that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/flanglet/kanzi

I have compiled it on Android with minor changes (I changed a String base switch statement IIRC). It is pure java with no dependencies (no required external libraries) and offer a vast choice of compression methods.